# How to resolve error with webpack-dev-server?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Often I get weird errors, when I try to run server: npm start. So, I dont know how to solve this, because there is not any explanations about error from Node. Can anyone say whats problem?

**On of them is:**

```
> angular-starter@6.0.0 webpack-dev-server D:\Projects\UI
> node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js "--config" "config/webpack.dev.js" "--open" "--progress" "--profile" "--watch" "--content-base" "src/"

 10% building modules 2/2 modules 0 activeError: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1258:14)
    at listen (net.js:1294:10)
    at net.js:1404:9
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:62:16)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:81:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! angular-starter@6.0.0 webpack-dev-server: `node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js "--config" "config/webpack.dev.js" "--open" "--progress" "--profile" "--watch" "--content-base" "src/"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-starter@6.0.0 webpack-dev-server script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Oleg\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-28T12_52_25_565Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! angular-starter@6.0.0 server:dev: `npm run webpack-dev-server -- --config config/webpack.dev.js --open --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-starter@6.0.0 server:dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Oleg\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-28T12_52_25_647Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! angular-starter@6.0.0 start: `npm run server:dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-starter@6.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Oleg\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-28T12_52_25_726Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Read the error message. It looks like port 3000 is already in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is angular 2 related issue, in webpack.dev.js typescript compiler is unable to start, Can you provide this file and also package.json.
So it will be easy to find the error

Comment: What leads you to believe that the typescript compiler cannot start?

Comment: I'm more interested to see you configuration files. error is in web pack dev server file configuration which is used to start ts compiler